# NUnit Tests failing on Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, nunit, selenium-grid

Im using Selenium Grid.  When I run a test against my test site, I will hit the following error.

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Session [(null externalkey)] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions. Active sessions are[]
```

The test does not fail immediately, but will navigate around the site and to different pages before failing.

My Hub set up is batch file as follows:

```
  cd C:\Automated Tests\Selenium
  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar -role hub -hubhost my.hub..ip.address     -port 4445
```

My Node set up is batch file as follows:

```
cd c:\Automated Tests\Selenium\
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar -port 5560 -role node -nodehost     my.node.ip.address -hub http://my.hub.ip.address:4445/grid/register -browser"browserName=firefox,version=33.0,maxInstances=2,platform=WINDOWS" -nodeTimeout 600 -maxSession 10
```

Theres not a lot of information on this issue, so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and I found the solution.

This might be occurring because of using old objects.

Try instantiating new objects of your web elements when you close and start new driver session.

In this case, it does not throw stale element exception but it niether finds the web element in DOM with old object reference and hence throws the error.